# Вывод информации о всех компьютерах домена

Tags: powershell

есть  скрипт, как получить данные не для одного компа а для всех компов домена

Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName computer01 | Select-Object -Property MACAddress, Description

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы применить эти командлеты к списку компьютеров нужно воспользоваться конвеерной обработкой используя `foreach`.

Для того чтобы получить список имен компьютеров в доменной сети нужно выполнить `LDAP` запрос к `ADSI` провайдеру.

```
#собираем информацию об именах компьютеров домена
$domainname = $env:userdomain #имя домена соответствует домену текущего пользователя 
[ADSI]$domain = "WinNT://$domainname"
$Search = [ADSISearcher]"(objectCategory=Computer)"
$Search.PropertiesToLoad.Add('Name')
$Results = $Search.FindAll()

#конвеерная обработка
[Array]$Computers = $Results.Properties.name
foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
    Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration `
                  -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" `
                  -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object -Property MACAddress, 
                                                                    Description
}
```